# Как изменить знаки всех элементов массива на противоположные?

Tags: java

Дано задание:
"1. инициализировать двумерный массив 10х10 случайными числами от -10 до 10 (не включительно).вывести его на экран.
2. изменить знаки  всех элементов массива на противоположные. вывести массив на экран"

Первую часть вроде сделал.
Не могу сообразить, как сделать пункт 2?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] second = new int[10][10];
    int min = -10;
    int max = 10;
    for(int i=0; i<second.length; i++)
    {
      for(int j=0; j<second[i].length; j++)
      {
        second[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*(max - min) + min);
      }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<second.length; i++)
    {
      for(int j=0; j<second[i].length; j++)
      {
        System.out.print(second[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Достаточно просто "повторить" математику 6 класса школьной программы, и вопрос отпадет сам по себе..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<second.length; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<second[i].length; j++)
  {
    second[i][j] = -second[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: Как элегантно))
Спасибо, не додумался...)